# How can I talk to a c# .dll in mIRC?

Tags: c#, mirc

Is there a way? I've noticed COM objects are there but someone said they only work with C/C++...

And even then, I'm not exactly sure what they are. I want to build a script for mIRC but I hate using MSL. Thank you. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523669/how-to-write-and-send-text-to-mirc-in-c-win32

Answer (score 2):

I did this many many years back.

The trick was to create a mixed-mode assembly/dll, and provide the necessary exports. The exported function would then call into .NET code for you to handle the request from mirc.

I will try see if I have the code still lying around (we are talking about 8 years back now).