# C# - Access to another application and send keys

Tags: c#

I want to control another application and send keys to the application `textBox1` , Also i want to access the app using `Application.Launch("Name.exe")`

```
Application application = Application.Launch("foo.exe");
Window window = application.GetWindow("bar", InitializeOption.NoCache);

Button button = window.Get<Button>("save");
button.Click();
```

And i need for sending keys like this answer ... but dont know how...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# using Sendkey function to send a key to another application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292175/c-sharp-using-sendkey-function-to-send-a-key-to-another-application)

Comment: this is not my answer...

Comment: Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055347/c-sharp-sendkeys-to-other-application-to-particular-textfield

Comment: Updated Question ...