# IPC in C#, sending text from one exe to another exe

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to send a message from a WPF application's textbox to an open notepad. After I click the button next to the the textbox, I would like the content is written into the notepad, I mean.

How can I send messages between 2 different applications ?

Comment: Are you assuming notepad is already open?

Comment: Thanks, supposing that it is open.

Comment: This should get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604070/write-text-to-notepad-with-c-win32

Comment: I just set these stuff aside for only a few months, now I am like a complete idiot about them. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please decide if your question is "how to send text to notepad" or "how to do IPC". (Side note: Consider deleting your comments and merge them into the question instead).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);

private static void DoSendMessage(string message)
{
    Process notepad = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe"));
    notepad.WaitForInputIdle();

    if (notepad != null)
    {
        IntPtr child = FindWindowEx(notepad.MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(0), "Edit", null);
        SendMessage(child, 0x000C, 0, message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For sending data between two applications you control, you could use [NamedPipeClientStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream.aspx) and [NamedPipeServerStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream.aspx)