# Launch the vba editor from excel by code

Tags: c#, excel, vba, vsto

In **Vsto-excel** project , i have a **macro** in a particular module.
By **code** in c#, i want to launch the VBA editor showing the given **macro**.
i know the interop concepts , but i m stuck at launching the vba editor and showing the particular macro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Application.Goto "MarcoName"` which will open up the VBE at the sub / macro you specify.

Comment: yes that worked fine ,.... but if i am having 2 workbooks opened and both have the macro with same name ...then active workBook's macro is called ??

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard shortcut ALT + F11 on a open excel sheet ,opens the VBA Editor by default.
Use the excel interop to open the excel and make the excel window visible .Then you can pass the keyboard shortcut to the excel window,from your application.

If you are using this on a winform application ,you can use the **sendkeys** method to pass the keyboard shortcut to the excel window.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx

otherwise use the **sendmessage** method to pass the keyboard shortcut across.Here is the so post on the sendmessage usage , [c# Sending keyboard commands to another window / process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605147/c-sharp-sending-keyboard-commands-to-another-window-process).