# Reuse the VBA Editor IDE in my own .NET Application

Tags: c#, vba, office-interop

Is there a VBA Editor part of the .NET Framework, or even the Office Solution where I can open up a pop-up on my C# .Net application that allows the user to write/update their VBA script with a normal VBA IDE?

Comment: Do you want to enable your application to support `VBA` and  use `VBA Editor` or you want to edit an existing macro of for example an excel file and save it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I already know how to run the vba code in .NET, but what I am looking for is a VBA Editor that I can incorporate into my code.

Comment: Isn't this what you are looking for? [Launch the vba editor from excel by code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701783/launch-the-vba-editor-from-excel-by-code)

Comment: Thanks, but no, as I would like for the VBA Editor to be in my application.  I don't mind Office needing to be installed, but I really prefer to have the VBA Editor open up on my application.

Comment: VBA *must* run inside another application (that's what the'A' stands for). The VBA editor is associated with the host application and cannot be run independently of it. So the answer to what you mention in your last comment - embedding the VBA IDE in your .NET application - is: NO, this is not possible as the VBA IDE is specifically designed to be associated with the host application.