# How can i programmatically use aero snap features from C# code

Tags: c#, winforms, operating-system, aero-snap

I have a simple question. How can I access aero snap programmatically from my C# code. Like, if I click a button "Snap Left", I want my program window to snap to the left, just like when its drug over there manually. I looked all over SO, but all the questions seem to be about aero snap not working with a form, and keeping it from snapping a form. Not programmatically snapping a form. I'm happy to use interloping. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do, assuming you are on Windows 7, is to send the AreoSnap Keypress to the currently active window.

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18366/Sending-Keystrokes-to-another-Application-in-C) codeproject has a very nice article on doing just that.

Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605147/c-sharp-sending-keyboard-commands-to-another-window-process) SO question.

It seems that one way to do this is use `sendmessage` in User32.dll.

Here is an example of this, assuming "notepad" is the program you want to send the keystroke to:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process [] notepads=Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
    if(notepads.Length==0)return;            
    if (notepads[0] != null)
    {
        IntPtr child= FindWindowEx(notepads[0].MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(0), "Edit", null);
        SendMessage(child, 0x000C, 0, textBox1.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well that's a cool idea! I think that should work. Thanks. +1

Comment: The example code appears to be sending WM_SETTEXT to Notepad's Edit control, setting its text. This has nothing to do with simulating Aero snap. My testing indicates that SendMessage will not trigger Aero snap, so I fail to understand why this answer was accepted or upvoted. I'm guessing that, as with other system hotkeys, Win-Left/Right is handled by the system and not by the target window procedure, so simulating it requires sending keystrokes at a higher level, such as with the SendInput API.