# Open internet explorer page using c#, invoke a ctrl + F keyboard shortcut and fill it out with certain keywords

Tags: c#, vb.net

I need to develop a Windows application in C# or VB.net, that when pressing a button, opens Internet Explorer to a specific URL, and invokes the search text function - as in, pressing the CRTL+F in keyboard and filling in specific text in the search textbox.

Currently I can open the page in IE using `process.start("iexplorer.exe","URL");`, but I don't know how to invoke the CRTL+F command after opening the page.

Appreciate your help

Comment: can you not use the webbrowser class within your app

Comment: What version(s) of IE are you targeting?

Comment: Simplest solution is to use `SendKeys.Send()`

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the SendMessage function
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Also, check out this question - [c# Sending keyboard commands to another window / process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605147/c-sharp-sending-keyboard-commands-to-another-window-process)