# Open File Dialog do not display initial file name correctly

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

Windows `OpenFile` Dialog do not display initial file name correctly:
[image]

The file name is scrolled to the left as it would be too long. If I choose the same file by a double-click, then its name is shown correctly.

The MFC's **`CFileDialog`** is used to create the `OpenFile` Dialog:

```
CFileDialog fileDialog(TRUE, nullptr, 
                       _T("GutenTagScript.vbs"), OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST, 
                       _T("VBS Files|*.vbs||"), this, 0);
```

The problem occurs **only** in `OpenFile` Dialog not in `SaveFile` Dialog.

Comment: Appears to be a [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24525606/1889329).

Comment: @IInspectable Ok, so it is some general Windows OS problem... I face the issue using C++ and you posted a link to a C# issue.

Comment: The C# code calls the same Shell functions. The only difference is in the interface, not the code that eventually runs.

Comment: It's actually difficult to determine where the problem is... See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60182612/default-filename-appears-truncated-in-windows-ifiledialog Since you're on C++, you can try to use IFileDialog directly see if the problem persist. I personally have no problem using the sample code (so as guys in the comment).

Comment: Shouldnt your filter string end `||`. And try using a buffer for the filename by modifying the `OFN` structure before it is displayed.

Comment: I can reproduce this issue using Win32 C++ application (using `IFileOpenDialog`). I'll submit an issue internally.