# Lua Alien - SendMessage to Notepad.exe with WinAPI

Tags: winapi, lua, ipc

I have compiled a bunch of online resources that got me to here.  Hopefully what I have is close.  Unfortunately I have no Windows Programming experience.  I come from a Linux background.  I am also new to [alien](http://alien.luaforge.net/) for Lua, but I know Lua well enough.

What I want to do is send a simple "Hello World" with `sendMessage()` from the `Win32 API` to a running `Notepad.exe` window.

I got the process ID from the command prompt with the following command:

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq notepad.exe" /FI "USERNAME eq user"
```

[image: notepad PID]

And I got the message to send code of 0x000C from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523405/how-to-send-text-to-notepad-in-c-win32).

So far this is what I have:

```
require "luarocks.require"
require "alien"

myTestMessage = 0x000C -- Notepad "Set text" id
notepadPID = 2316      -- Notepad Process ID

-- Prototype the SendMessage function from User32.dll
local SendMessage= alien.User32.SendMessageA
SendMessage:types{ret ='long', abi = 'stdcall','long','long','string','string'}

-- Prototype the FindWindowExA function from User32.dll
local FindWindowEx = alien.User32.FindWindowExA
FindWindowEx:types{ret = 'long', abi = 'stdcall', 'long', 'long', 'string', 'string'}

-- Prototype the GetWindowThreadProcessID function from User32.dll
local GetWindowThreadProcessId = alien.User32.GetWindowThreadProcessId
GetWindowThreadProcessId:types{ret = 'long', abi = 'stdcall', 'long', 'pointer'}

local buffer = alien.buffer(4) -- This creates a 4-byte buffer

local threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(notepadPID, buffer) -- this fills threadID and our 4-byte buffer

local longFromBuffer = buffer:get(1, 'long') -- this tells that I want x bytes forming a 'long' value and starting at the first byte of the
                             -- 'buffer' to be in 'longFromBuffer' variable and let its type be 'long'

local handle = FindWindowEx(threadID, "0", "Edit", nil); -- Get the handle to send the message to

local x = SendMessage(handle, myTestMessage, "0", "Hello World!") -- Actually send the message
```

A lot of this code was pieced together from the [Lua alien documents](http://alien.luaforge.net/), [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/aa904962), and some Google searches ([namely this result](http://www.tcbmi.com/strokeit/forum/read.php?5,54896,54905,quote=1)).

Is there anyone out there who could be a hero and explain to me what i'm doing wrong, and how I should go about this.  And, most importantly, why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing GetWindowThreadProcessId() and FindWindowEx(). The first parameter to both of them is an HWND handle to the desired window, but you are passing a process ID to GetWindowThreadProcessId() and a thread ID to FindWindowEx(), both of which are wrong.

There is no straightforward way to get an HWND from a process ID. You would have to use EnumWindows() to loop through the currently running windows, calling GetWindowThreadProcessId() on each one until you find a matching process ID to the one you already have.

Answer (score 2):

I eventually found a simpler way to do this using both [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [FindWindowEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from the Windows API.  This way you can find correct handles to the parent and children processes of Notepad.

```
-- Require luarocks and alien which are necessray for calling Windows functions
require "luarocks.require"
require "alien"

local SendMessage= alien.User32.SendMessageA
SendMessage:types{ret ='long', abi = 'stdcall','long','long','string','string'}

local FindWindowEx = alien.User32.FindWindowExA
FindWindowEx:types{ret = 'long', abi = 'stdcall', 'long', 'long', 'string', 'string'}

local FindWindow = alien.User32.FindWindowA
FindWindow:types{ret = 'long', abi = 'stdcall', 'string', 'string'}

local notepadHandle = FindWindow("Notepad", NULL )

local childHandle = FindWindowEx(notepadHandle, "0", "Edit", nil)

local x = SendMessage(childHandle, "0x000C", "0", "Hello World!") -- Actually send the message
```