# Visual Studio Code: The type or namespace name 'IntPtr' could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

How can I get the code submitted by user "Brian" at [How to send text to Notepad in C#/Win32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523405/how-to-send-text-to-notepad-in-c-win32) to work in Visual Studio Code.

I did a "Dotnet add package System.Runtime" and that seem to add the System.Runtime package, but I am still get a compile error:
WriteNotepad.cs(10,50): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IntPtr' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Stephen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IntPtr is in the System namespace so include this up top.

using System;